# Создание объекта через литерал

Tags: jquery, javascript

помогите пожалуйста поправить скрипт http://prozaik.16mb.com/js3/huYak/

я пытаюсь создать объект игрока с определёнными в коде начальными координатами, но консоль показывает непонятные мне ошибки

объект создаю не через оператор new, а как советует стоян стефанов в книжке "js шаблоны", через литерал

код:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ PLUGIN kalininHuyak IMPLEMENTATION------------
function KalininHuyak(options){
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ properties ---------  
    init();

    var huyakWrap = options.huyakWrap,
        playerOffset = 10,
        player = document.getElementById('player');

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ methods ------------  
    function init(){
        playerShip.appendPlayer(playerShip.createPlayer(), 200, 500);       
    }

    playerShip = {
        var xPosition,
            yPosition;

        function createPlayer(){    
            var player = $('<div />',{
                    class: 'player',
                    id: 'player'
                });

            return player;
        }

        function appendPlayer(player, x, y){
            xPosition = x;
            yPosition = y;

            player.appendTo('#huyakWrap');

            player.attr('style', 'left: ' + x + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px');
        }

        function movePlayer(direction, offset){
            var playerPositionX = player.style.left,
                currentOffset = parseInt(playerPositionX, 10),
                preCurrentOffset = currentOffset + (offset * direction);

            if(preCurrentOffset < 0){
                preCurrentOffset = 0;
            }
            else if(preCurrentOffset > 920){
                preCurrentOffset = 920;
            }

            player.style.left = preCurrentOffset  + 'px';
        }
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ handlers -----------      
    function onKeypress(keyCode){
        var direction;

        if(keyCode == 49){
            direction = -1;
        }
        else if(keyCode == 50){
            direction = 1;
        };

        playerShip.movePlayer(direction, playerOffset);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ events -------------  
    $(window).keypress(function(e){
        onKeypress(e.which);
    });
};
```

Comment: Перед тем как читать о шаблонах какого-либо языка программирования, нужно хотя бы синтаксис языка выучить. Вы явно не знакомы с синтаксисом javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
var xPosition,
```

Переменные нельзя объявлять в теле объекта. Там должны быть только свойства и методы - пары ключ-значение, разделенные двоеточием. каждая пара отделяется запятой.

```
ReferenceError: KalininHuyak is not defined
    var kalininHuyak = new KalininHuyak({
```

Попытка использования необъявленного конструктора KalininHuyak.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в объявлении объекта `playerShip`. Почитайте, как правильно [объявляются свойства объектов](http://learn.javascript.ru/object#объявление-со-свойствами). И да, пидумайте для своей программы, имён переменных и дивов какие-нибудь цензурные названия.